# Thickness and refractive index of silica gel layer between fused silica and water interface

Tags: water, refraction

I learned that when fused silica contact with water, a layer of silica gel will be formed. However, I cannot find any reference about the thickness and the refractive index of the silica gel. Can anybody kindly tell anything about these? Any information about these is welcomed, thanks!

Reference

[1] Yaminsky, V. V., B. W. Ninham, and R. M. Pashley. "Interaction between surfaces of fused silica in water. Evidence of cold fusion and effects of cold plasma treatment." Langmuir 14.12 (1998): 3223-3235.

[2] Sulpizi, Marialore, Marie-Pierre Gaigeot, and Michiel Sprik. "The silica–water interface: how the silanols determine the surface acidity and modulate the water properties." Journal of chemical theory and computation 8.3 (2012): 1037-1047.

Comment: Such a layer should be very thin, likely monomolecular. Its optical effect should be very small indeed. Look for the RI of silica gel on refractiveindex.info.